# Errors when creating layer in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, wms

I am trying to create raster layer mosaic time dimension plugin. I have created `datastore`, `timeregex` and `indexer` files based on settings in existing working layers. After creating layer, I can't see any data in layer preview, only black pixels and gray_index set to zero.

**Edit:**
I switched to verbose logging and tried to reproduce error with layer consisting of rasters already running behind existing layers, but everything worked fine. I guess this narrows It down to actual problem with rasters.

Output from GeoServer working layers:

```
2022-06-12 09:35:43,999 DEBUG [geotools.jdbc] - CREATE CONNECTION
2022-06-12 09:35:44,003 DEBUG [data.jdbc] - exporting PropertyName
2022-06-12 09:35:44,003 DEBUG [geotools.jdbc] - SELECT min("ingestion") FROM "public"."t2m"
2022-06-12 09:35:44,005 DEBUG [geotools.jdbc] - CLOSE CONNECTION
2022-06-12 09:35:44,017 INFO [geoserver.wms] - 
Request: getMap
    Angle = 0.0
    BaseUrl = http://localhost:8080/geoserver/
    Bbox = SRSEnvelope[12.672434907113352 : 35.97501363262053, 34.464999543113265 : 47.54499877841993]
    BgColor = java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=255]
    Buffer = 0
    Clip = null
    CQLFilter = null
```

Output from GeoServer not working layer:

```
2022-06-12 09:15:28,910 DEBUG [geotools.jdbc] - CREATE CONNECTION
2022-06-12 09:15:28,910 DEBUG [data.jdbc] - exporting LogicFilter
2022-06-12 09:15:28,910 DEBUG [data.jdbc] - exporting PropertyName
2022-06-12 09:15:28,910 DEBUG [data.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2022-06-12 09:15:28,910 DEBUG [data.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2022-06-12 09:15:28,910 DEBUG [data.jdbc] - exporting SQL ComparisonFilter
2022-06-12 09:15:28,910 DEBUG [data.jdbc] - exporting PropertyName
2022-06-12 09:15:28,910 DEBUG [data.jdbc] - exporting PropertyName
2022-06-12 09:15:28,910 DEBUG [geotools.jdbc] - SELECT "location","ingestion",ST_AsEWKB("the_geom") as "the_geom" FROM "public"."sp" WHERE ("the_geom" && ST_GeomFromWKB(?, 4326) AND "ingestion" = ? AND "ingestion" IS NOT NULL )
2022-06-12 09:15:28,910 DEBUG [geotools.jdbc] - 1 = POLYGON ((13.273016488845716 34.045000000000115, 30.26948593598513 34.045000000000115, 30.26948593598513 46.61500000000059, 13.273016488845716 46.61500000000059, 13.273016488845716 34.045000000000115))
2022-06-12 09:15:28,910 DEBUG [geotools.jdbc] - 2 = 2022-06-05 12:00:00.0
2022-06-12 09:15:28,910 DEBUG [gce.imagemosaic] - Trying to resolve path:
type:RELATIVE
parentLocation:file:/home/user/geoserver/geoserver-2.19.0-bin/bin/../data_dir/data/sp/
location:sp_2022060512.tiff
2022-06-12 09:15:28,911 INFO [gce.imagemosaic] - Unable to read image for file file:/home/user/geoserver/geoserver-2.19.0-bin/bin/../data_dir/data/sp/sp_2022060512.tiff
2022-06-12 09:15:28,911 DEBUG [imagemosaic.catalog] - Skipping invalid granule
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal argument: "granuleLocation=sp_2022060512.tiff".
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Please extract the relevant part of the log file and add it to the question

Comment: The Internet is too dangerous a sewer to follow links. If the only way your problem can be understood is to follow the link, then it's likely to be closed as *unclear*.

Comment: there are no errors in the part of the log you have posted. Please try to generate the problem again and then post that part of the log

Comment: does `/home/user/geoserver/geoserver-2.19.0-bin/bin/../data_dir/data/sp/sp_2022060512.tiff` exist and can tomcat (or whoever is running GeoServer) read and write to that directory

Answer (score 1):

Eventually, it turned out that it was an issue with metadata.

gdalinfo of correct tiff was:

```
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
```

whereas problematic one was:

```
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  GRIB_cfName=surface_air_pressure
  GRIB_cfVarName=sp
  GRIB_gridDefinitionDescription=Latitude/Longitude Grid
  GRIB_gridType=regular_ll
  GRIB_iDirectionIncrementInDegrees=0.03
  GRIB_iScansNegatively=0
  GRIB_jDirectionIncrementInDegrees=0.03
  GRIB_jPointsAreConsecutive=0
  GRIB_jScansPositively=1
```

After applying:

```
   raster=rasterio.open(output_filename)
   data=raster.read()                
   nds=rasterio.open(
        output_filename,
        'w',
        driver='GTiff',
        compress="LZW",
        blockxsize=128,
        blockysize=128,
        height=height,
        width=width,
        count=1,
        dtype=data.dtype,
        crs='+proj=latlong',
        transform=transform,
        tags={'AREA_OR_POINT': 'Area'},
        )
    nds.write(data)
    nds.close()
```

everything worked fine.